# How can I change the default message for the terms and services, and is it possible to do so from the Keycloak admin console?

Tags: keycloak

[registraion page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFjve.png)

I followed the steps from a Stack Overflow discussion and added terms and conditions to my Keycloak registration page, but I want to change the default message 'Terms and conditions to be defined' to a link or something else. How can I do that? Is it possible to do this from the admin console?

I attempted to go to the localization page and add HTML tags with 'termsKey' text and 'terms_and_conditions' text, but it didn't change anything.